# How to get Tabularor cell and row objects from element

Tags: javascript, user-interface, tabulator

I have a Tabulator table that has the following icons at the last column of each row, set by a custom formatter:

```
function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    return '<i class="bi bi-pencil row-edit"></i> <i class="bi bi-trash row-delete"></i>';
};
```

When either of the icons is clicked, I get a reference to the target element that received the click event.

How can I get the `cell` and the `row` from that element?

To clarify, I realize that I can listen on the cellClick event and get the target element from it, but I want to get the cell from the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cellClick` callback to get both `cell` and `row`,
as well as the clicked element.  Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      field: 'name'
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      field: 'age'
    },
    {
      title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender'
    },
    {
      title: 'Height',
      field: 'height'
    },
    {
      title: 'Color',
      field: 'col'
    },
    {
      title: 'Edit',
      field: 'Edit',
      formatter: (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) => {
        return '<i class="bi bi-pencil row-edit"></i> <i class="bi bi-trash row-delete"></i>'
      },
      cellClick: (e, cell) => {
        const icon = e.target.classList[2]
        const rowNum = cell.getRow().getPosition()
        const colName = cell.getColumn().getField()

        console.log(`'${icon}' icon of row ${rowNum} in '${colName}' column was clicked.`)
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />

<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: I know that I can listen on the cell event, but I want to get the cell from the elements, and not the elements from the cell

Comment: The elements (I am assuming you mean the icons you click on) don't have any cell or row information.  They area just DOM elements.  If there is a specific cell or row data you want to include in these elements, you can do so in your formatter function by assigning a data tag to them. Ex: `\`<i class="bi bi-pencil row-edit" data-rowno="${cell.getRow().getPosition()}"></i>\``.  Then you can get this data using `e.target.dataset.rowno` from your click event listener.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: I realize that I can get it that way, but I am pretty sure that there is a way to retrieve the cell from the element, which is what I am after

Comment: Well, I tried. I guess I really don't understand what you mean by 'retrieve the cell from the element'.  Hope someone else can chime in and provide the answer you are looking for.